# How to code independent variables that have infinity as their value in multiple regression?

Tags: r, multiple-regression

I'm performing a standard multiple linear regression on telecommunications data and one of the variables can have infinity/unlimited as its value. e.g. number of minutes has a series of discrete values but can also be infinity.

I can create a separate 0/1 variable to capture the "unlimited minutes" records but then how to I add the extra information that I have for plans that have a discrete number of minutes? A colleague suggested contriving a number of minutes to be 100,000 say but I'm not convinced this is the right way to go.

I'm using R to do this modelling

Comment: How can it be infinity? It might be unknown, or censored, but number of minutes cannot be infinite. Please describe your data more.

Comment: If "infinity" means "you can talk for an unlimited number of minutes per month", then you are constrained by the maximum number of minutes a month can have. Except for months during which you switch to or from daylight saving time, this maximum number is $31\times 24\times 60=44640$. (I suspect entering this into a linear regression as a predictor will not be useful. Much better to include a "limited/unlimited" Boolean predictor.)

Comment: One possibility is to code the missings (which are what these infinities are) as 0 and also to have an indicator 1 for missing and 0 otherwise as an extra predictor which gives you an offset for the effect of infinite versus finite values. Arbitrary replacements such as 100000 are in contrast just about the worst possible solution. They will create a class of outliers and do so arbitrarily and you will spend much of the analysis henceforth fighting the consequences of that .

Comment: Yes you're right - I'm asking more about how to code such variables. I can always add a Boolean 0/1 to mean "unlimited" vs "capped" but I'd also like to add the amount that the plan is capped by. I also have the same problem for the 'downloads' variable where I have the option that a customer can have unlimited (or infinite?) downloads.

Comment: I also thought about reversing the concept and transforming the data to be log(1/x)...so the "infinite" values would have 0 value in this transformation. (although I know it's not mathematically pure)

Answer (score 2):

[Infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity) is not a number. Any mathematical operation on infinity would output infinity. Including infinite values in your regression analysis data this would not lead to any meaningful results. In fact, most software would prohibit you from using infinite values.

Moreover, no real-life data contains infinite values. If such variables were "measured", than this means that you have problems with precision of your measurement instrument, so it returns meaningless output. If this is about coding that you used, then change it to use meaningful categories: ask yourself what does "infinity" mean in case of your variable?

Comment: Yes you're right - I'm asking more about how to code such variables. I can always add a Boolean 0/1 to mean "unlimited" vs "capped" but I'd also like to add the amount that the plan is capped by. I also have the same problem for the 'downloads' variable where I have the option that a customer can have unlimited (or infinite?) downloads.

Comment: @vw262363 Even if user has "unlimited" number of minutes to use or downloads, than in reality he can make only a limited number of calls (limited by time available, but also by time to sleep, eat, work etc.), the same with downloads. Definitively it is not infinite value. Using dummy variables seems to be a good idea (as also noted in comments).

Comment: Thanks everybody - seems we are all on the same page. I ended up using dummy variables and created levels based on downloads level and a separate one for Unlimited downloads. The model is behaving itself now.